# Vectr graphics program

Tags: vector-graphics

I want to create a simple header containing colored text and a simple sketch, and colored background, with the colors being standard computer colors, and to save it in something like jpg so that it is recognized by the Linux server. But I'm having a lot of difficulty find a suitable program.

I downloaded Vectr but get this message; "This type of file can harm your computer. Do you wand to keep Vectr-win64 anyway?" - Keep - Discard - I have not yet clicked any.

Does anybody know if Vectr is safe, or know of a suitable program?

Comment: You could use Word and take a screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Vectr.com is completely safe to use. That free vector graphics editor is being used currently by tens of thousands people worldwide.

The reason you're getting the message is that your AV pattern may be outdated. Vectr has passed most of the certifications and users don't usually have the problem with warning messages.

Disclaimer: I am part of Vectr's team.

Comment: OK, thank you. I've downloaded what I thought is your program but I'm getting a console suggesting I login. That is not normal for a program. Does creating an account & logging in open the program?

Comment: Yes indeed it does.